# How to customize/styling forms using class based views

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

Is it possible to customize the HTML attributes of the form created by class base views?
At this moment, I'm using a generic CreateView:

```
class SlipCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Atum
    fields = ['atum1', 'atum2', 'atum3', 'atum4', 'atum5', 'atum6', 'atum7']
```

I want to change, for example, the length and position of the input fields, the color, and others attributes. Is this possible? And if yes, how?

Thank you advance.